# Symbol Rotation for all features along line in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, symbology, rotate, attribute-rules

I have a waterline with accesories set along the pipes and I would like to rotate the symbols towards the pipe direction (Paralel, perpendicular, etc Depending on the fitting or device type). For that, I created a Simbol Rotation field which does it by writting the angle, and it works fine but I have to do, object by object individually and this will take ages for all the network.

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Example: Take all Tees on the network and rotate them all in one step depending on the direction of the pipes

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Attribute Rule in Field 'rotation' (add first). Then apply 'rotation by attribute' in Symbology.

Attribute Rule:

```
// Find the first intersecting line from the intersecting class
var lineClass = FeatureSetByName($datastore, "Line_tes", ["objectid"], true)
var line = First(Intersects(lineClass, $feature))

// If no feature was found, return the original value
if (line == null)
return $feature.rotation

// Buffer the point by a small amount to extract the segment
var search = Extent(Buffer($feature, .01, "meter"))
var segment = Clip(line, search)["paths"][0]

// Start and end points of the line
var x1 = segment[0]['x']
var y1 = segment[0]['y']
var x2 = segment[-1]['x']
var y2 = segment[-1]['y']

// Arithmetic angle (counter-clockwise from + X axis)
var degrees = Atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / PI;
return (degrees + 360) % 360;
```